# Spring Boot: "No qualifying bean of type... found" when autowiring concrete class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am writing a component using Spring Boot and Spring Boot JPA. I have a setup like this:

The interface:

```
public interface Something {
    // method definitions
}
```

The implementation:

```
@Component
public class SomethingImpl implements Something {
    // implementation
}
```

Now, I have a JUnit test which runs with `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`, and I want to test my `SomethingImpl` with this.

When I do

```
@Autowired
private Something _something;
```

it works, but

```
@Autowired
private SomethingImpl _something;
```

causes the test to fail throwing a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` with the message `No qualifying bean of type [com.example.SomethingImpl] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

But in the test case, I want to *explicitly* inject my `SomethingImpl` because it is the class I want to test. How to I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a special bean you have to use the `@Qualifier` annotation:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("SomethingImpl")
private Something _something;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. It must be also noted that the string in the `@Qualifier` must be set to the `@Component` like `@Component("SomethingImpl")`.

Answer (score 4):

I figured out you can do the same with a `javax.inject` style DI:

```
@Named("myConcreteThing")
public class SomethingImpl implements Something { ... }
```

Where you want to inject it:

```
@Inject
@Named("myConcreteThing")
private Something _something;
```

This is correctly picked up by `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan`.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to add @Service in implementing class.. like

`@Service
public class SomethingImpl implements Something {
    // implementation
}`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I could resolve the issue by adding component scan path to the Application class 
as below:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"xx.xx"})
```